# No space between inline-block elements in IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, css

[Consider the following code:](http://jsfiddle.net/4twSs/)

HTML:

```
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Stack</div>
<div>Overflow</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

In IE8, as well as in other modern browsers, there is a space between the `div`s:

[image]

However, in IE7, the `div`s are adjacent to each other. There is no space between them.

How could I make sure that IE7 has this space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the space yourself for only IE7 and lower:

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    *margin-right: 0.25em;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Or like this:

```css
div + div {
    *margin-left: 0.25em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some background on the spaces/inline-block issue: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

So you can implement one of those fixes (to remove the spaces) and then specifiy a margin value. Or, you can simply float them and specify a margin value instead:

```
div {
    background-color: #ccc;
    float: left;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE7 only has partial support for inline-block. Basically IE6 and IE7 support inline-block only on elements with a display of "inline" by default.

Divs default display is block so IE7 ignores your inline-block and only reads the inline hence the no space issue.

To fix it you can try to add the non-breaking white space (`&nbsp;`) between elements although it gives you inconsistent behaviour between older browsers and new browsers since in the later the space between elements is bigger (`&nbsp;` + margin).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that IE7 (and earlier) will insert a space (if there is whitespace in the markup) before an ‘inline-block’ element if it is preceded by some text (a non-breaking space will do), and will do so *even if that text has `display:none;`* (though it will not insert a space after the ‘inline-block’ before any text following).

So a solution to the OP which will render consistently cross-browser would be to change the HTML thus:

```
<div>Hello</div>
<!--[if lte IE 7]><span style='display:none;'>&nbsp;</span><![endif]-->
<div>Stack</div>
<!--[if lte IE 7]><span style='display:none;'>&nbsp;</span><![endif]-->
<div>Overflow</div>
```